# EspExceptionDecoder missing from Arduino tools menu

Tags: exception, arduino-esp8266

I am running Arduino:

```
Version: 2.1.0
Date: 2023-04-19T15:31:10.185Z
CLI Version: 0.32.2
```

I have installed EspExceptionDecoder.jar in:

```
C:\Users\<my username>\Documents\Arduino\tools\EspExceptionDecoder\tool
```

(C:\Users<my username>\Documents\Arduino\tools already existed)

Once the jar file was copied into the appropriate folder, I rebooted the Arduino IDE.

I can't find EspExceptionDecoder in the tools menu.

Any help would be most welcome!

Comment: IDE 2 is written in typescript so it can't use plugins written for IDE 1 in Java. use the command line version of the stack decoder

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, the ESPExceptionDecoder only supports Arduino IDE version 1.9 below. Arduino version 2++ above not supported. See this video for your reference. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ve9-74TRHUM&ab_channel=DonskyTech